# Extract price suffix in € (google sheet)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell with this text:

> "Chalet independiente en **Montealegre**, Barcelona **425.000 €**. URBILARO.
> COM les ofrece en exclusiva esta fantástica vivienda ubicada en
> Barcelona. Parcela de 613 mts2 con jardín consolidado, paellero y
> piscina. Su interior se distribuye en un ...
> [http://st1.idealista.com/static/common/release/home/resources/img/logo-small.png]
> [https://www.idealista.com/?xts=582065&xtor=EPR-1147-[express_alerts_20220629]-20220629-[logo]-72485519100@1-20220629170428]Hola,
> Idealist, 1 anuncio recién publicado con tus criterios
> [https://img3.idealista.com/blur/500_375_mq/0/id.pro.es.image.master/63/6d/8c/1001269200.jpg]
> [https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/**98106051**/?xts=582065&xtor=EPR-1147-[express_alerts_20220629]-20220629-[Property.New.Photo]-72485519100@1-20220629170428&isFromSavedSearch=true]
> Ver 30 fotos
> [**https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/98106051/**?xts=582065&xtor=EPR-1147-[express_alerts_20220629]-20220629-[Property.New.Photo]-72485519100@1-20220629170428&isFromSavedSearch=true]
> Chalet independiente en Montealegre, Barcelona
> [https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/98106051/?xts=582065&xtor=EPR-1147-[express_alerts_20220629]-20220629-[Property.New.Link]-72485519100@1-20220629170428&isFromSavedSearch=true]
> 425.000 € **152 m²** **4 hab**. URBILAR. COM les ofrece en exclusiva esta fantástica vivienda ubicada en La Barcelona. Parcela de **613 mts2** con
> jardín consolidado, paellero y piscina. Su interior se distribuye en
> un .........................."

The information structure for others cells, is similar to this one.

I want to extract the bold information in different cells:

For instances:

| Montealegre | 425.000 € | 98106051 | 152 m² | 4 hab | 613 mts2 |

I tried to start with the price, like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT('Hoja 1'!B1; "\€([0-9.]+)")
```

But no luck.

You can see sample here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u0ItzOo50-aGv2yXzGxS_TzfsHFUmPZJ4hcwA8jswfM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
=REGEXEXTRACT('Hoja 1'!B1; "[0-9. ]+€")
```

(Remember the space.)